# Preserve Timestamp on TIDAL FTP file transfer

Tags: tidal-scheduler

When we transfer files with a module for Python, original timestamps are maintained from the server.  When we transfer files with the FTP plugin for TIDAL, timestamps are marked as the time the file was downloaded from the source.

Is there any switch or property somewhere, that I can modify, to preserve the original timestamps?